# How to fix error "_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "200 600 1000"

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a rage game in Tkinter Python 3.11.2 and I tried to put a function for easy, normal and hard difficulties.
easy giving you 200 milliseconds to click, (check code)
normal giving you 150 milliseconds to click, (check code)
hard giving you 100 milliseconds to click, (check code)

I tried to implement this, it was fine before.

Code:

```
# You try to click a circle, but when you hover over it, it disappears

from tkinter import *
import random

gui = Tk()

def titlescreen():
    gui = Tk()

    gui.configure(bg="limegreen")

    gui.title("Rage Game Title screen")

    gui.geometry("480x240")

    play = Button(gui, text=' PLAY ', font='helvetica,24')
    play.pack()
    gui.after(1000000,gui.destroy)

gui.after(1, lambda: gui.focus_force())

gui.resizable(False, False)

gui.configure(bg="limegreen")

gui.title("Rage Game")

gui.geometry("1280x800")

gui.resizable(False, False)

my_label=Label(gui, text="",font='helvetica,12')
my_label.pack(pady=50)  

but_loc_x=[200,600,1000]
but_loc_y=[200,350,600]
zbut_loc_x=[200,600,1000]
zbut_loc_y=[200,350,600]
obut_loc_x=[200,600,1000]
obut_loc_y=[200,350,600]

def press():
    my_label.config(text="You pressed me.\n Well done\n")   
    gui.after(1500,gui.destroy)

def button_hover_hard(q):
    gui.after(100)
    obut_pos_x=random.choice(obut_loc_x)   # <----- moved into the function
    obut_pos_y=random.choice(obut_loc_y)   # <----- moved into the function

def button_hover_easy(q):
    gui.after(200)
    zbut_pos_x=random.choice(zbut_loc_x)   # <----- moved into the function
    zbut_pos_y=random.choice(zbut_loc_y)   # <----- moved into the function
    
def button_hover(e):
    gui.after(150)
    but_pos_x=random.choice(but_loc_x)   # <----- moved into the function
    but_pos_y=random.choice(but_loc_y)   # <----- moved into the function

    rage_button.place_configure(x=but_pos_x,y=but_pos_y)
    rage_button2.place_configure(x=obut_loc_x,y=obut_loc_y)
    rage_button3.place_configure(x=zbut_loc_x,y=zbut_loc_y)

def easy1234():
    rage_button2.place_forget()
    rage_button.place_forget()

def normal1234():
    rage_button3.place_forget()
    rage_button.place_forget()

def hard1234():
    rage_button3.place_forget()
    rage_button2.place_forget()
    
#def unhover(e):
   # root.after(500)
    #button.place_configure(x=600,y=350)

easy = Button(gui, text=' EASY ', font='helvetica,24', command=easy1234)
easy.place(x=10,y=10)
easy1 = Button(gui, text=' NORMAL ', font='helvetica,24',  command=normal1234)
easy1.place(x=10, y=50)
easy2 = Button(gui, text=' HARD ', font='helvetica,24',  command=hard1234)
easy2.place(x=10,y=90)

rage_button3 =Button(gui,text=" Try to \n click me \n >:) ",borderwidth=0,command=press,height=3, width=5 )
rage_button3.place(x=600,y=350,anchor=CENTER)

rage_button3.bind("<Enter>",button_hover_easy)

rage_button2 =Button(gui,text=" Try to \n click me \n >:) ",borderwidth=0,command=press,height=3, width=5 )
rage_button2.place(x=600,y=350,anchor=CENTER)

rage_button2.bind("<Enter>",button_hover_hard)

rage_button =Button(gui,text=" Try to \n click me \n >:) ",borderwidth=0,command=press,height=3, width=5 )
rage_button.place(x=600,y=350,anchor=CENTER)

rage_button.bind("<Enter>",button_hover)
#button.bind("<Leave>",unhover)

gui.mainloop()
```

If I do this, I get the following error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1948, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "", line 71, in button_hover
> rage_button2.place_configure(x=obut_loc_x,y=obut_loc_y)
> File "c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2504, in place_configure
> self.tk.call(
> _tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "200 600 1000"

I am using VS Code's interactive Window function to run my code.

Here is my system info:

- Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz
- Installed RAM 16.0 GB
- x64 operating system, x64-based processor
- Windows 10 Enterprise, version 22H2
- OS build 19045.3086
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to randomize the second and third buttons. Instead, you're passing the raw position lists, as in `obut_loc_x=[200,600,1000]` instead of a random item from that list.

```py
def button_hover(e):
    gui.after(150)
    but_pos_x=random.choice(but_loc_x)
    but_pos_y=random.choice(but_loc_y)

    # Added the next four lines:
    obut_pos_x=random.choice(obut_loc_x)
    obut_pos_y=random.choice(obut_loc_y)
    zbut_pos_x=random.choice(zbut_loc_x)
    zbut_pos_y=random.choice(zbut_loc_y)

    rage_button.place_configure(x=but_pos_x,y=but_pos_y)
    # And changed the args here:
    rage_button2.place_configure(x=obut_pos_x,y=obut_pos_y)
    rage_button3.place_configure(x=zbut_pos_x,y=zbut_pos_y)
```

You should probably group the locations better (what happens if you have 10 buttons?), but the change above should fix your error.

Comment: Now it only moves once, and if you press the easy normal and hard buttons (corner) they don't work (as they delete the buttons but after that it does not move the button when you hover over it.. It may be an error in my coding, but I can't seem to find it. Anyways, please fix this! Otherwise, you answer works! (kinda because of this issue).

Comment: @THEOP05 The StackOverflow Q&A format is not good for back-and-forths like this. You'll get much better responses if you post a new question with a minimal reproducible example, and a careful description of the problem.

Comment: BTW I grouped everything together, and looked at your fixed code and now I made a whole new game mode! (impossible mode). Thank you for sharing your code. My game would not have been possible without you. Thank you.